# Why doesn't Ukraine use its control on Russian pipelines as negotiation leverage?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine

Ukraine could threaten both Russia and Europeans to blow up or simply shut down the pipelines passing on their territory if Russians get too aggressive and if Europeans do not convince Putin to calm down. Why don't they do it?

Comment: "to blow up" ?? How exactly would they do it? Can it not easily be repaired if you blow it up on only a single place? Or would you have to blow it up the whole length, which would then be a major task?

Comment: Blow it up at some strategic points...

Comment: I have not idea about the efficiency of pipeline blow ups, but I guess it's not in use currently anyway. So there wouldn't be any immediate effect. This pipeline won't decide the War for them.

Comment: If they just turn it off Russia can turn it back on.   Destroying a short section of the pipeline would not put it out of action for long unless Russia wished to cut the gas of to Europe.

Comment: @IanRingrose "Destroying a short section of the pipeline would not put it out of action for long" I don't think so. Ukraine can choose to blow up the session where their military forces have advantages over Russia's. If Russia sends any repairmen, they would have to be under attack as well... Also they can use guerilla to destroy different sessions or pipeline randomly... I am pretty much sure it is much easier to destroy than to restore.

Comment: https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/is-war-ukraine-impacting-russian-gas-supplies-europe-2022-03-07/ This article is quite related

Answer (score 12):

- We don't know what they are warning in private.
- With Nord Stream 2, there is enough *capacity* to bypass Ukraine. (That's what ex-President Trump's rhetoric got wrong a couple of years ago. Nord Stream doesn't make Europe *much* more dependent on Russia, it makes Europe and Russia less dependent on Ukraine.)
- Transit fees are a significant income source for Ukraine. Blowing the pipelines would remove this potential for years to come.

Comment: Nord Stream 2 is not in function now. And I don't think loosing the transit fees is a bigger lost than what they are loosing under the Russian bombs. Putting everything in the balance, shutting down the pipelines is probably less expensive.

Comment: "Blowing the pipelines would remove this potential for years to come." Not sure if Ukraine cares much about this at the moment.

Comment: @Trilarion The current government may be gone soon, but the country is going to be there for decades to come. And it's not like a scorched earth tactic is going to keep the government in control anyway.

Comment: @Trilarion, Nord Stream 2 is off because the EU wants it off. The brotherhood and soyuz pipelines are on as long as both Russia and the EU want it on. If the next winter gets colder than this one, will the EU give in?

Comment: "...will the EU give in?" Nobody knows. But if they are smart, they better not. Appeasement doesn't work. History has proven that.