# Why is Ukraine not stopping the transit of Russian gas in the context of its demand to boycott Russian gas?

Tags: ukraine, sanctions, gas

As can be seen in [this article](https://www.rnd.de/politik/krieg-in-der-ukraine-selenskyj-ruft-deutsche-zu-boykott-von-russischem-gas-auf-ZGCA4WM3XDJOLQKJ5BL2KWI3TU.html) from Germany, Zelenskyj calls for a gas boycott from Russia. At the same time, there is the transit of Russian gas through Ukraine. So why is Ukraine not stopping that transit, if they don´t want Germany and other European countries to buy Russian gas?

A translation of the main part of the linked article:

> KIEV. Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelenskyy has called on the
> Germans to boycott Russian gas and other goods. "Without trade with
> you, without your companies and banks, Russia will not have the money
> for this war," the 44-year-old said in a video message shared on
> social media on Monday. Nobody has the right to destroy peoples and
> divide up Europe.

This question is completely different than [this one](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71065/why-doesnt-ukraine-use-its-control-on-russian-pipelines-as-negotiation-leverage), it is in context of the request made by Zelenskyj and described in the article. It is not about speculative possibility of Ukraine stopping the transit.

Just as update Nord Stream I is also out of question now.

Comment: It still appears as if the answer from the other question would answer this.

Comment: @Joe W Not really, but posibly because I was not really able to explain the exact concern. So to sumarize the question, is why Ukraine helping european countries to buy russian gas, if they don´t want them to buy it?

Comment: @convert Ukrainian goal was integrating into Europe - if they upset the Europeans, it will mean that their fight against Russia is pretty much pointless (I assume that the loss of the material currently sent by Europe is negligeable compared to what they get from the US).

Comment: How is that not answered in the previous question about stopping the transport of the oil/gas?

Comment: @JoeW situation in Ukraine has change this last month. Also, Nord Stream II is out of question now.

Comment: Sounds like the other question should be updated rather then spread the answers across two questions

Comment: @Joe W This question is related to the demand by Ukraine, which the other one is not.

Comment: @Roger Vadim But Ukraine has already demanded from Europe to stop buing gas and oil from Russia, so europeans will not have enough of oil and gas. But you saing this will not upset the europeans?

Comment: @Roger Vadim So just to not upset european coutries Ukraine should help their enemy to sel gas and oil?

Comment: It seems that Ukraine stops some of the transit. Is it a risky move?

Answer (score 11):

Apparently the question was reopened because

> Nord Stream II is out of question now.

Well, maybe. If Ukraine does something dramatic and blows up the pipelines, NS II could be quickly opened. Its approval process was just suspended, as far as I can tell. The pipeline is fully built.

It's also worth noting that some countries like Hungary already seem to bypass Ukraine more than before by getting more of their Russia gas [via](https://www.rferl.org/a/hungary-russia-gazprom-gas/31479747.html) the other fairly new pipeline from Turkey (through Bulgaria and Serbia--[opened](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/world/serbia-opens-pipeline-for-russian-gas-ignoring-u-s-opposition) in Jan 2021).

> Under the deal, Gazprom would ship 4.5 billion cubic meters of natural gas to Hungary annually, allowing the supply of around half of Hungary's annual gas consumption.
>
> Two routes will be used -- 3.5 billion cubic meters will come via Serbia and 1 billion cubic meters via Austria.

Some of these Eastern EU countries like Hungary and Bulgaria did give their half-hearted approval to the EU to send weapons to Ukraine, but they completely [ruled out](https://sofiaglobe.com/2022/03/18/bulgarias-pm-dismisses-talk-of-supplying-weapons-to-ukraine/) sending any weapons themselves. Hungary even blocks any weapons for Ukraine from [even](https://www.reuters.com/world/hungary-will-not-allow-lethal-weapons-ukraine-transit-its-territory-fm-2022-02-28/) transiting Hungarian territory. If Ukraine does something to annoy these countries even more, Hungary could e.g. start blocking EU decisions on helping Ukraine, which by the way, they used to do with regard to Ukraine's NATO membership.

And probably even Poland, Slovakia, and Romania, which are sending weapons (or at least ammo in Romania's case) to Ukraine, would object to suffering a sudden energy crisis since they still [get](https://english.alarabiya.net/News/world/2022/03/11/Russian-gas-flows-on-key-pipelines-to-Europe-remain-steady) a sizeable fraction of their natural gas from Russia, via Ukraine.

By the way, [according](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2022/02/why-europe-cant-shut-off-russian-gas/622925/) to one analyst, NS2 was supposed to be the "final nail in the coffin" of gas transit through Ukraine, given the other pipelines that Russia has built in the meantime:

> the role of Ukraine is smaller today than it was in the late ’90s. There was a time when 90 percent of the gas that comes from Russia to Europe went through Ukraine. Now it’s less than a quarter. So all the stuff people say, like “Nord Stream 2 is going to kill Ukraine and [gas] transit,” like, yes, Nord Stream 2 is the final nail in the coffin of a Ukrainian transit story that has been in demise for 25 years.

According to the same source, cutting EU's gas imports from Russia would hurt the EU more than Russia, because the latter makes relatively little profit from natural gas relative to oil sales. (Although no figures are provided.) Somewhat simplified pipeline supply explanation map, from the Economist:

[image]

The EU itself is trying wean off the Russian gas, [but](https://www.reuters.com/business/energy/europe-faces-struggle-escape-russian-gas-this-year-2022-03-17/)...

> One of the biggest hurdles to replacing so much gas this year is securing enough LNG.
>
> The [EU] Commission says around 10 bcm of gas imports could come from alternative pipeline suppliers, while 50 bcm would be LNG. That is equivalent to around 10% of annual global LNG supply.
>
> "Obtaining this volume will be difficult: 50 bcm would represent a major additional draw on an already-tight global LNG market and additional demand cannot be met by significant new capacity before the mid-2020s," Jesse Scott at German-based thinktank Agora Energiewende said. [...]
>
> U.S. exporters have shipped record volumes of LNG to Europe for three consecutive months, at prices at least 10 times higher than a year ago.

The cost (for the EU) of entirely replacing the Russian supplies has been estimated at around one hunderd billion euros per year, given current prices.

Answer (score 4):

The decision to purchase gas (or anything else, for that matter) from Russia  is viewed typically as a decision that can *only* be made by each sovereign country that wants to buy the said gas. And, of course, Russia must agree to sell that gas, and the two parties must agree on the price and other specifics, etc.

**It is not up to Ukraine** or any other third party to break up a business contract such as this. In fact, insufficient energy supplies may create conditions conducive to internal unrest and regime change in the affected countries, and could be viewed as interference in the internal politics of these sovereign countries. Would Ukraine want to play kingmaker in, say, Germany, which supplies Ukraine with aid? Unlikely. Hence, the gas will continue to flow as long as there are gas buyers and gas sellers. All Ukraine can do is ask the German government to stop buying Russian gas (note that German population is mostly sympathetic to Ukraine).

Remember that allegedly or actually committing war crimes is not viewed uniformly as a reason to terminate business contracts with the offending country: Nazi Germany maintained excellent business relationships with many companies from the "civilized" countries, while committing war crimes, which were widely reported in the world mass media.

**REFERENCES:**

Germans approve of government U-turn on Ukraine: https://www.dw.com/en/germans-approve-of-government-u-turn-on-ukraine/a-61011528
To drive, or not to drive: Germans rethink love of cars: https://www.reuters.com/business/autos-transportation/drive-or-not-drive-germans-rethink-love-cars-2022-03-18/

Hitler's American Business Partners (2003) - A detailed, well-referenced, and chilling look at American multinational corporations who fuelled and profited from the Nazi movement before and during the US involvement in WWII. Including Standard Oil, Texaco, Ford, GM and IBM. [00:48:15]: https://www.reddit.com/r/Documentaries/comments/tk0k15/hitlers_american_business_partners_2003_a/

Comment: The example with Nazi Germany is a good one, but as far I know there were no business relationships with countries in a state of war with Nazi Germany, like GB after 1940.

Comment: "It is not up to Ukraine or any other third party to break up a business contract such as this." Mayne during peacetime, but during wartime, the Russian gas pipelines would be legitimate military targets. All they'd have to do is plant a few bombs or shoot a few anti-tank missiles at them to cause a leak.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Because they're qt war with Russia, and punishing Russian collaborators is a reasonable war goal, to remove monetary support from Russia. If a German pensioner dies of the cold because of a gas shortage, then it's their own fault for collaborating with Russia.

Comment: @TimurShtatland "It's not their fault" So? It's a war. Fault doesn't matter, hurting the enemy matters.

Comment: @TimurShtatland There are people in Ukraine who are dying for reasons that are not their fault, too.

Comment: @user253751 I think there's too much focus on what's good/bad morally compared to what's expedient politically and strategically. Ukraine is not going to turn off the pipeline to the west, not because they care very deeply about German pensioners, but because doing so would hurt them more than it would hurt Russia. The "West" is committing many resources to fund the war in Ukraine. Destroying the pipeline would hurt the West and would very likely be deemed a hostile act. At least by citizens. The cost of losing support is bigger than the gains of cutting off Russia from the West's gas money.

Comment: "My point is that Germany, and every other country that buys gas from that Russian pipeline may take it as a violation of their sovereignty." That would be absurd. It's not a violation of a country's sovereignty to refuse transit. There are political reasons for Ukraine to not block transit, but no legal ones.  "And really, why should Ukraine decide whether the German industry has to buy gas from other sources" because it's their country. "What if even one German old person dies from being too cold & catching pneumonia or flu, etc?" That's emotional blackmail

Comment: @Acccumulation is correct. And also keep in mind that the gas sales involve not just a contract between Russian and German entities, but also with one or more Ukrainian entities  for the transit. Because the gas is transiting Ukraine, Ukraine is part of this business deal and has just as much sovereign right as any of the other parties to continue with or terminate it.

Answer (score -1):

[Money don't smell](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-03-21/ukraine-says-russia-still-pays-in-hard-currency-for-gas-transit), Ukraine is still getting money for transit of Russian gas and oil. Nord Stream 2 was born dead and Nord Stream 1 will stop soon, so Ukraine will stay the only way for transit of Russian gas. The Russian transit is the only real way for Ukraine to get oil and gas as only alternative would be getting that goods from Europe by train.

It looks like money defenetly play an important role since the only demand from Ukraine to Russia for futher transit was increase in tariffs, at least acording to [this Russian article](https://eadaily.com/ru/news/2022/12/24/rossiya-namerena-sohranit-prokachku-nefti-cherez-ukrainu-sobytiya-nochi-24-dekabrya):

> Russia plans to maintain the volume of oil pumping through the Druzhba
> pipeline through Ukraine, Deputy Foreign Minister Mikhail Galuzin said
> in an interview with RIA Novosti. "On December 20, in an interview
> with the Rossiya-24 TV channel, the president of Transneft (Nikolay)
> Tokarev said that next year the volume of oil pumping through the
> southern branch of the Druzhba oil pipeline to Hungary, Slovakia and
> the Czech Republic will remain at the level of this year," the
> diplomat said. The representative of the department clarified that the
> Ukrainian side had contacted Transneft to discuss transit. "As far as
> we know, in November, Transneft confirmed receipt of a notification
> from Ukrtransnafta about an increase in tariffs for pumping oil
> through the Druzhba pipeline running through the territory of Ukraine
> from January 1, 2023," Galuzin said.

Comment: What you are saying is very true, but it is playing only a minor part in the decision to open/close the pipeline through the Ukraine. Relations with the EU Partners that are now providing Assistance and aid to Ukraine and the Ukrainian people is very high on the list and completely outweighs the financial benefit that the pipeline provides.